How to define table hints in Flink SQL Window VTF
I am trying to do a stats query by Flink SQL Windowing TVF aggregation on an iceberg table with streaming read mode.
How can I use table options hint with Flink Window TVF? What's the correct syntax?
The SQL is like this, Get Synxtax Error by SQL-Client
-- create connect table
CREATE TABLE default_catalog.default_database.`test_p` (
  id BIGINT,
  t BIGINT, 
  dt STRING,
  ts AS CAST(TO_TIMESTAMP_LTZ(t, 3) AS TIMESTAMP(3)),
  WATERMARK FOR ts AS ts - INTERVAL '5' SECOND
) 
PARTITIONED BY (dt)
WITH (
  'connector'='iceberg',
  ...
);

SET execution.runtime-mode = streaming;
SET table.dynamic-table-options.enabled = true;

/*+ OPTIONS('streaming'='true', 'monitor-interval'='15s')*/

-- Syntax error !
SELECT * FROM 
TABLE (
  TUMBLE(
    TABLE test_p ,
    DESCRIPTOR(ts),
    INTERVAL '5' MINUTES
  )
) /*+ OPTIONS('streaming'='true', 'monitor-interval'='15s')*/; 

